# Dismiss an Alarm using power Button?

Tags: android

From the Answers to the other questions I found here, it seems it is not possible to listen to hardware buttons such as Power Buttons from a service, However, My need is to dismiss an alarm when the power button is pressed. Is it possible in Android, anyway to achieve that?  Here is my Alarm Service code:

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {
private NotificationManager alarmNotificationManager;

public AlarmService() {
super("AlarmService");
}

@Override
public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
sendNotification("Wake Up! Wake Up!");
}

private void sendNotification(String msg) {
Log.d("AlarmService", "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
alarmNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent(this, Time_Date.class), 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder alamNotificationBuilder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(

this).setContentTitle("Alarm").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);


alamNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
alarmNotificationManager.notify(1, alamNotificationBuilder.build());
Log.d("AlarmService", "Notification sent.");
}
}
```

Comment: Check out : http://code4reference.com/2012/08/enabling-disabling-broadcast-receiver-during-runtime/

Comment: But sadly that doesn't show any info on dismissing an Alarm  by pressing a Hardware button

Comment: it´s not possible to listen to the power button, instead You can do a similar action like listen to screen go to sleep/come from sleep.....